# Automatically allow (include) all packages from the public registry in a specific view on Azure Devops Server

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

We are using Azure Devops Server (on-premise in other words).

The public npmjs registry (https://registry.npmjs.org) is added as an upstream source so within our feed we store our own packages and all packages that anyone consumes from the public npmjs registry.

We also use the default views (@prerelease en @release) for promoting our own packages.

Unfortunately it turns out that when we restrict use to this view (in .npmrc) also every package from the public registry needs to be promoted to release, which is a huge bummer.

> Is there any way that we can set to allow (include) all packages from the
> upstream public registry source in a specific view. (In our case this
> would be @release)

Or alternatively, is there a way to select all public registry packages and then promote them all at once?

Answer (score 0):

In the end we adopted a workaround.
We now have two feeds and use npm scopes :

1. one "Packages" feed has our companies feed that use the standard feeds @local, @release and @prerelease.
   All the teams publish to this feed and promote their packages when ready for release.
2. the second "PublicPackages" feed only has the @lobal feed and allows downstream resources

All "consumers" then have an .npmrc that set the "PublicPages" feed as the default and adds the "Packages" feed as a [npm scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/scopes?view=azure-devops) :

```
registry=https://tfsserver/<project_name>/_packaging/PublicPackages/npm/registry/ 
@[SCOPE_NAME]:registry=https://tfsserver/<project_name>/_packaging/Packages%40Release/npm/registry/ 
always-auth=true
                        
; begin auth token
; Treat this auth token like a password. Do not share it with anyone, including Microsoft support. This token expires on or before 2-1-2024.
//tfsserver/<project_name>/_packaging/Packages%40Release/npm/registry/:username=****
//tfsserver/<project_name>/_packaging/Packages%40Release/npm/registry/:_password=***
//tfsserver/<project_name>/_packaging/Packages%40Release/npm/registry/:email=***
//tfsserver/<project_name>/_packaging/Packages%40Release/npm/:username=***
//tfsserver/<project_name>/_packaging/Packages%40Release/npm/:_password=***
//tfsserver/<project_name>/_packaging/Packages%40Release/npm/:email=***
; end auth token

; begin auth token
//tfsserver/<project_name>/_packaging/PublicPackages/npm/registry/:username=***
//tfsserver/<project_name>/_packaging/PublicPackages/npm/registry/:_password=***
//tfsserver/<project_name>/_packaging/PublicPackages/npm/registry/:email=***
//tfsserver/<project_name>/_packaging/PublicPackages/npm/:username=***
//tfsserver/<project_name>/_packaging/PublicPackages/npm/:_password=***
//tfsserver/<project_name>/_packaging/PublicPackages/npm/:email=**
; end auth token
```

[Note that we could have used the public npm registry in combination with a scope package for our companies packages. It's for auditing that we set up the PublicPackages feed.]